# Issues with Maven project for Hibernate tutorial

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven

I am following the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch01.html) and trying to create a Maven project in my eclipse. I have created a new maven project by selecting default options shown in eclipse except for `groupId, artifactId and version` details which I have selected (`org.hibernate.tutorials, hibernate-tutorial, 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` respectively) based on the information present in `pom.xml` shown in Hibernate documentation. After that I have replaced the `pom.xml` file in my project with the one shown in documentation. Then I have added version details for each of the dependencies which are missing in the documentation. Here is my final `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.hibernate.tutorials</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-tutorial</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>First Hibernate Tutorial</name>

<build>
     <!-- we dont want the version to be part of the generated war file name -->
     <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Because this is a web app, we also have a dependency on the servlet api. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate uses slf4j for logging, for our purposes here use the simple backend -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now in eclipse I see below errors:

```
1) Maven Configuration Problem:

Failure to transfer
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
Could not transfer artifact
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to
central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was
cancelled.

2) Maven Problems:

CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-compile: PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.3.2 (): ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1: UnresolvableModelException: Failure to transfer org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-containers:pom:1.0.3 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-containers:pom:1.0.3 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.

3) Maven Problem:

CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-testCompile: PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to transfer org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.4.1 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.4.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.

4) Maven Problem:

Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)

5) Maven Problem:

Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)

6) Maven Problem:

Project configuration is not up-to-date with pom.xml. Run Maven->Update Project or use Quick Fix.
```

**Update:** When I build the project in eclipse I am getting below error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'hibernate-tutorial'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
```

Please help me how can I fix these issues. I am blocked at first step of learning Hibernate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fixed you internet connection: `Could not transfer artifact
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to
central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was
cancelled.`. proxy etc. Not related to Maven itself.

Comment: see if you are running from behind the proxy. maven needs internet connection without blockages

Comment: I am connected to internet and I am sure that I don't have any proxy in between. But is there a way to check if there is any proxy? please suggest.

Comment: I have used `http://www.whatismyip.com/` and it says that there is no proxy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exit eclipse

Remove (or rename to be safe) your .m2/repository directory, it will be located in your [home directory](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Where+is+my+home+directory+located%3F) on your machine.

Start eclipse, right click your project, select Update Maven Project, check Force Update of Snapshots/Releases, press OK

Comment: Thanks a lot Kharyam, issue is fixed after following your steps. Can you please tell me how these steps fixed the issue? because I have created this basic project so why Maven is complaining with so many issues for the first time, is it good to use Maven?

Comment: @user2065083 no problem. My guess is there was a temporary connection issue that occurred when the dependencies were initially loaded. Maven tries to be smart by disallowing you from retrying for a set amount of time (to ease the load on the remote maven repository server).  Most times this is not what we want.  My suggestion was heavy handed but you could have also just deleted the directory in your repo for the artifact(s) that failed. Maven prevents even worse things from happening (dependency hell) so I would advise using it or its descendants (e.g., gradle, Ivy for ant)

Comment: Thank you, I think I had internet connection problem for few seconds when I was creating the project, so I think that created the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It did not allow me to rename .m2 dir. Below are the detailed steps which resolved my error:
* I removed project from Eclipse
* Exited Eclipse
* Deleted (not shift deleted) .m2 folder from C/Users/Kshitija/ location
* Opened Eclipse, created maven project again
* Right clicked on the project -> Maven -> update project -> selected an option of "check Force Update of Snapshots/Releases", press OK
as soon as project is built, the error disappeared